# My 1st Jnr Web Dev pre-interview challenge - advice please

Tags: html, css

I've got my first junior web developer pre-interview challenge, where I have to replicate an image they have sent me of a web page in to a functioning web page.

I've been teaching myself coding on and off for years and while I am rusty, I want to give this my best shot possible.

My question is; what is the best way to create this and send it over to them? Do I just create it as an .html file on my editor and send that across to them as an attachment, or is there a better/more professional way to do it?

TIA for any help

R x

Comment: Why don't you ask "them" how they want you to submit it.

Comment: I just wasn't sure if it was a standard way for this type of thing to be given that I was unaware of, and just wanted to see if I could find it out before asking, is all  - if there is no right / wrong way to do it, only down to preference I shall ask. Thank you :)